# Pandas series: Apply a combination of two aggregates to a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregate, eval

Consider the following Pandas series:

```
s = df.groupby(df.index.date)['value'].agg(['count', 'nunique'])
print(s)

            count  nunique
2009-01-03      1        1
2009-01-09     14        1
2009-01-10     61        1
2009-01-11     93        1
2009-01-12    106        8
```

To calculate a linear combination of these two aggregates as `count - nunique + 1`, one solution would be to use `eval` method as follows:

```
s = df.groupby(df.index.date)['value'].agg(['count', 'nunique'])
s.eval('C = count - nunique + 1', inplace=True)
print(s)

            count  nunique   C
2009-01-03      1        1   1
2009-01-09     14        1  14
2009-01-10     61        1  61
2009-01-11     93        1  93
2009-01-12    106        8  99
```

My question is, is there another solution based on `apply` method? What I'm thinking about is something like  :  `sr.apply(agg('count') - agg('nunique') - 1 )`

Comment: Maybe I don't get it, but why this use of `eval`? You could just do `s['C'] = s['count'] - s['nunique'] + 1`. And if you want to avoid the temporary `DataFrame` as you said below, well then you have to aggregate separately: `df.groupby(df.index.date)['value'].agg(['count']) - df.groupby(df.index.date)['value'].agg(['nunique']) +1` but I don't consider this better

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I think the same that there is no better solution than aggregate them separately in order to avoid the intermediate df.

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
sr = out.groupby(out.index.date)['value'].agg(['count', 'nunique'])
sr['C'] = sr.apply(lambda x: x['count'] - x['nunique'] +1 , axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your  answer. I was wandering how we can apply combined aggregation functions without computing the resulted field 'count' and 'nunique'?